# su -u www-data cat ... not working as expected

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, setfacl

For a project I'm working on, I need the www-data user to be able to read /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/index.txt

The permissions see fine for this:

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data 1050 Dec  7 20:43 index.txt
```

That wasn't working so I added ACL.

```
getfacl index.txt
# file: index.txt
# owner: root
# group: www-data
user::rw-
user:www-data:r--
group::r--
mask::r--
other::---
```

No matter what, it doesn't work. There must be something I'm doing wrong here?

```
sudo -u www-data ls index.txt
ls: cannot access 'index.txt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to check the permissions of the containing directory and all parent directories, which must at least allow the `x` search permission for that user in order to access files or directories within that directory (and `r` permission if reading the directory listing is desired).

Comment: That worked. thanks! quick question though. If I access the file from a different directory, do I still need x permission in that folder?

Comment: Do you mean by a symbolic link? You would also need permission to read the link and access the directory that it is in.